# Modify APA reference style to show Capital Author name, but citation still show normal text

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apa6

I'm trying to get the reference following my graduate school.

My Graduate school claimed that the bibliography formats were adopted from APA style of bibliography and citation with some modifications.

> AUTHOR, A.A.A., AUTHOR, B.B.B., AUTHOR, C.C.C., AUTHOR, D.D.D.,
>   AUTHOR, E.E.E., & AUTHOR, F.F.F. (Year of publication). Book title in
>   sentence case (edition if later than the first). Place of Publication:
>   Publisher.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{report} 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{apacite}
\begin{document}
shortciteA{Mukhtar2011} mentioned that...... 
The result \shortcite{Mukhtar2011} .........
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{dummy}
\end{document}
```

**dummy.bib**

```
@article{Mukhtar2011,
    Author = {M. S. Mukhtar and A.-R. Carvunis and M. Dreze and P. Epple and J. Steinbrenner and J. Moore and M. Tasan and M. Galli and T. Hao and M. T. Nishimura and S. J. Pevzner and S. E. Donovan and L. Ghamsari and B. Santhanam and V. Romero and M. M. Poulin and F. Gebreab and B. J. Gutierrez and S. Tam and D. Monachello and M. Boxem and C. J. Harbort and N. McDonald and L. Gai and H. Chen and Y. He and J. Vandenhaute and F. P. Roth and D. E. Hill and J. R. Ecker and M. Vidal and J. Beynon and P. Braun and J. L. Dangl},
    Doi = {10.1126/science.1203659},
    Journal = {Science},
    Number = {6042},
    Pages = {596--601},
    Publisher = {American Association for the Advancement of Science ({AAAS})},
    Title = {Independently Evolved Virulence Effectors Converge onto Hubs in a Plant Immune System Network},
    Url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1203659},
    Volume = {333},
    Year = {2011}
    }
```

Following these texts, they will generate reference like this below,

[image]

but I would like to have

> MUKTAR, M. S., CARVUNIS, A.-R., DREZE, M., EPPLE, P., STEINBRENNER,
>   J., MOORE, J.,TASAN, M.,   Galli, M., HAO, T. ,  NISHIMURA,  M. T., 
>   PEVZNER, S. J.,   DONOVAN, S. E. & DANGL, J. L. (2011). Independently
>   evolved virulence effectors converge onto hubs in a plant immune
>   system network. Science, 333(6042), 596–601. Retrieved from
>   http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1203659 doi: 10.1126/science.1203659

One more concern is that I want the reference show the all of author, not like this the first, the second, the third,....., the last author. (2012)......

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.